# Why does my camelCase attributes work well with TypeScript but show an error in JS in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm working with my own React component library in coded in TypeScript, which I use with React JS projects. When I use my components in TypeScript they work well with their attributes, but in JS I have errors in the console. Exemple:

TS component:

```js
const Button: React.FC<props> = ({ btnStyle, ...otherProps }) => { ...component }
```

Types declaration:

```js
interface props {
    btnStyle?: string,
}
```

Component used in JS or TS:

```js
<Button btnStyle="plain">Button</Button>
```

And the error I get:

```bash
React does not recognize the `btnStyle` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `btnstyle` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

How could I use camelCase like in TS in JS?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing `btnStyle` to a non-React component like `button` (notice the lower case)?

Comment: No, I'm only passing to this one, which I use with Styled components

Comment: Check that you are importing your Button component, I tried the code and it works fine

Comment: Did you write the `props` interface yourself?

Comment: Yes but this is just to show, the final code is way larger, I just put what's useful in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem, it's coming from Styled Components, which puts the props on the generated HTML:

```html
<button btnStyle="style">Button</button>
```

This is how I fixed it:

```
import React from "react"

interface props {
    $btnStyle?: string
}

const Button: React.FC<props> = ({ btnStyle, children, ...otherProps }) => {
    return (
        <button $btnStyle={btnStyle} {...otherProps}>{children}</button>
    )
}
```

Check [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props) for the documentation

Comment: What is that `btnStyle` prop supposed to do on a regular button?

Comment: This is just to show how to fix it, the final code is not this